# Different view alternates with Orchard Multi-Tenancy

Tags: orchardcms, multi-tenant

I have an Orchard CMS installation with the Multi-Tenancy module enabled and 2 tenants set-up. Both tenants are using the same theme.

What I want is to be able to create view alternates to target each tenant, so that for example:

`~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content.Tenant1.cshtml` would target tenant 1 and 
`~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Content.Tenant2.cshtml` would target tenant 2.

I realise that I *could* do it with 2 different (yet very similar) themes, but that feels like needless duplication.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is of course to inherit from `ShapeDisplayEvents` and bind to the `context.ShapeMetadata.OnDisplaying` event thus:

```
public class MultiTenancyAlternatesFactory : ShapeDisplayEvents
{
    private readonly ShellSettings _shellSettings;

    public MultiTenancyAlternatesFactory(ShellSettings shellSettings)
    {
        _shellSettings = shellSettings;
    }

    public override void Displaying(ShapeDisplayingContext context)
    {
        context.ShapeMetadata.OnDisplaying(displayingContext =>
        {
            var tenant = _shellSettings.Name;

            // look for ContentItem property
            ContentItem contentItem = displayingContext.Shape.ContentItem;

            // if not, check for ContentPart 
            if (contentItem == null)
            {
                ContentPart contentPart = displayingContext.Shape.ContentPart;
                if (contentPart != null)
                {
                    contentItem = contentPart.ContentItem;
                }
            }

            var shapeName = displayingContext.ShapeMetadata.Type;

            if (contentItem != null)
            {
                var contentTypeName = contentItem.ContentType;

                displayingContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add(shapeName + "__" + contentTypeName + "__tenant__" + tenant);
            }

            displayingContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add(shapeName + "__tenant__" + tenant);

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement your code above but it only works for shapes.

I wanted to have a view of Index-tennant-[TenantName].cshtml to override Index.cshtml

To do this I had to override the RazorViewEngineProvider and then add in extra paths for the ViewEngine to look for. I used the [OrchardSuppressDependency...] as I don't like making changes to the actual Orchard CMS code because this then it makes any future upgrades much more painful.

I hope this helps anyone who comes up with the same problem with multi tenancy in orchard.

```
[UsedImplicitly]
[OrchardSuppressDependency("Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngineProvider")]
public class RazorViewEngineProvider : Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngineProvider, IViewEngineProvider, IShapeTemplateViewEngine
{
    private readonly string _tenant;
    public RazorViewEngineProvider(ShellSettings shellSettings)
    {
        _tenant = shellSettings.Name;
    }

    public new IViewEngine CreateThemeViewEngine(CreateThemeViewEngineParams parameters)
    {
        var viewEngine = base.CreateThemeViewEngine(parameters);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_tenant))
        {
            var razorView = viewEngine as RazorViewEngine;
            if (razorView != null)
            {
                razorView.PartialViewLocationFormats = addTenant(razorView.PartialViewLocationFormats);
                razorView.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = addTenant(razorView.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats);
            }
        }

        return viewEngine;
    }

    public new IViewEngine CreateModulesViewEngine(CreateModulesViewEngineParams parameters)
    {
        var viewEngine = base.CreateModulesViewEngine(parameters);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_tenant))
        {
            var razorView = viewEngine as RazorViewEngine;
            if (razorView != null)
            {
                razorView.ViewLocationFormats = addTenant(razorView.ViewLocationFormats);
                razorView.PartialViewLocationFormats = addTenant(razorView.PartialViewLocationFormats);
                razorView.AreaViewLocationFormats = addTenant(razorView.AreaViewLocationFormats);
                razorView.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = addTenant(razorView.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats);
            }
        }

        return viewEngine;

    }

    private string[] addTenant(string[] views)
    {
        var tenantedView = new List<string>();
        foreach (var view in views)
        {
            if (view.EndsWith(".cshtml",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                tenantedView.Add(string.Format ("{0}-tenant-{1}.cshtml", view.Substring(0,view.Length - 7) ,_tenant));
            tenantedView.Add(view);
        }
        return tenantedView.ToArray();
    }
}
```